# Rspec is failing for request header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am writing a code which will call some 3rd party API. So, I am using the API_HELPER module to call the 3rd party api.

```
module ApiHelper
    def self.get_header(header)
      @request['Accept'] = header[:accept].blank? ? 'application/json' : header[:accept]
      @request['Content-Type'] = header[:content_type].blank? ? 'application/json' : header[:content_type]
  end
end
```

and here is Rspec for this helper file:

```
describe '.get_header' do
    let(:request) { double('request') }

    before do
      allow(ApiHelper).to receive(:get_header).and_call_original
      allow(ApiHelper).to receive(:instance_variable_get).and_return(request)
      allow(request).to receive(:[]=)
    end

    context 'when header values are provided' do
      let(:header) { { accept: 'application/json', content_type: 'application/json' } }

      it 'sets the Accept and Content-Type header values' do
        ApiHelper.get_header(header)
        expect(request).to have_received(:[]=).with('Accept', 'application/json')
        # expect(request).to have_received(:[]=).with('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      end
    end

    context 'when header values are not provided' do
      let(:header) { {} }

      it 'sets default values for the Accept and Content-Type headers' do
        ApiHelper.get_header(header)
        expect(request).to have_received(:[]=).with('Accept', 'application/json')
        expect(request).to have_received(:[]=).with('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      end
    end
  end
```

But I run this spec, it is showing the error:

```
Failures:

  1) ApiHelper.get_header when header values are provided sets the Accept and Content-Type header values
     Failure/Error: expect(request).to have_received(:[]=).with('Accept', 'application/json')
     
       (Double "request").[]=("Accept", "application/json")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("Accept", "application/json")
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/helpers/api_helper_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ApiHelper.get_header when header values are not provided sets default values for the Accept and Content-Type headers
     Failure/Error: expect(request).to have_received(:[]=).with('Accept', 'application/json')
     
       (Double "request").[]=("Accept", "application/json")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("Accept", "application/json")
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/helpers/api_helper_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.23741 seconds (files took 1.39 seconds to load)
4 examples, 2 failures
```

I can't understand what will correct rspec for this code.

Answer (score 0):

`@request` is not tied to your `double('request')`.

This is actually a bit tricky to test, because it is a module.

One approach is to create a class to mix in the module.

```
class ControllerHarness
  include ApiHelper

  def initialize request
    @request = request
```

Then instantiate the class with the test double.

```
let(:controller) { ControllerHarness.new(request) }
```